# MS Excel - dynamic form

Tags: excel

I have created a workbook containing multiple worksheets, each containing a comprehensive forecast /budget spreadsheet.  I am attempting to use one standard structure for all worksheets.  How can I create a 'master reference' worksheet, that when I make changes to this worksheet all the other worksheets in the workbook get automatically updated? So, for example, if my master worksheet contains the rows (1) Business Revenue (2) Investment Revenue  (and 20 other worksheets reference this same structure) and I change the master worksheet to  rows (1) Business Revenue (2) asset sale revenue (3) Investment Revenue, I want the other 20 worksheets to automatically update to the new master sheet structure.

I hope this is clear.  Cheers!

Comment: Will the other sheets have any data in them?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new sheet, then use cell references to the master sheet.

For example:
=Sheet1!A1

That would get put in workbook Sheet2, cell A1

The problem will be how the data gets on the non-master sheets.  If you change the structure of the master, you will need to move the data to correspond on each sheet.

Comment: Yes, that is the issue that I am trying to solve.  How can I have the non-master sheets update automatically when a change (addition or deletion of rows) is made to the master.